# Run Redis Insights in Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to run Redis Insight in Docker Compose and I always get errors even though the only thing I'm changing from the Docker Run command is the volume. How do I fix this?

docker-compose.yml

```
redisinsights:
  image: redislabs/redisinsight:latest
  restart: always
  ports:
    - '8001:8001'
  volumes:
    - ./data/redisinsight:/db
```

logs

```
redisinsights_1  | Process 9 died: No such process; trying to remove PID file. (/run/avahi-daemon//pid)
redisinsights_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
redisinsights_1  |   File "./entry.py", line 11, in <module>
redisinsights_1  |   File "./startup.py", line 47, in <module>
redisinsights_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
redisinsights_1  |     self._setup(name)
redisinsights_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
redisinsights_1  |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
redisinsights_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
redisinsights_1  |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
redisinsights_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
redisinsights_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
redisinsights_1  |   File "./redisinsight/settings/__init__.py", line 365, in <module>
redisinsights_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
redisinsights_1  |     mkdir(name, mode)
redisinsights_1  | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/db/rsnaps'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the below steps to make it work:

Step 1. Create a Docker Compose file as shown below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redislabs/redismod
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  redisinsight:
    image: redislabs/redisinsight:latest
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
    volumes:
      - ./Users/ajeetraina/data/redisinsight:/db
```

Step 2. Provide sufficient permission

Go to Preference under Docker Desktop > File Sharing and add your folder structure which you want to share.

Please change the directory structure as per your environment

Step 3. Execute the Docker compose CLI

```
docker-compose ps
          Name                        Command               State           Ports         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pinegraph_redis_1          redis-server --loadmodule  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
pinegraph_redisinsight_1   bash ./docker-entry.sh pyt ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp
```

Go to web browser and open RedisInsight URL.
Enjoy!

Comment: Whats setting for headless docker running on linux(chromebook)? and i am not sure why we need to set this should docker not manage it by itself like it does for other containers? also the same compose file works on mac some how this error come for only chromebook..

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is deprecated, you can use now the following snippet for configuring Redis with RedisInsight using `docker-compose`. See the documentation [here](https://redis.io/docs/install/install-redisinsight/install-on-docker/):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    environment:
      REDIS_PASSWORD: secret
  redis-insight:
    image: redis/redisinsight:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5540:5540"
    volumes:
      - redis-insight:/data

volumes:
  redis-insight:
```

*If you don't want to persist the Redis Insight data, feel free to remove the `volumes:` definition*

Comment: He's right. This one works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on a Linux machine. I was able to solve it through the [Installing RedisInsight on Docker](https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/installing/install-docker/)
  page of redis.

> Note: Make sure the directory you pass as a volume to the container
> has necessary permissions for the container to access it. For example,
> if the previous command returns a permissions error, run the following
> command:
>
> `console $ chown -R 1001 redisinsight`