# How to secure RedisInsights on a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, redisinsights

I have redis running in a docker container with docker-compose and I found this article that shows how to run redisinsights from the same docker host.

[Run Redis Insights in Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197399/run-redis-insights-in-docker-compose/66829831)

I can expose port 8001 to 443 publicly to something like https://redisinsights.mysite.com.  Is there a straight forward way I can add a password that must be entered before redisinsights open?  If I just set it up, anyone who goes to that URL will see my data which would be bad.

Here is the insecure docker-compose from that post:

```
redisinsights:
  image: redislabs/redisinsight:latest
  restart: always
  ports:
    - '8001:8001'
  volumes:
    - ./data/redisinsight:/db
```

Comment: RedisInsight was designed to be a desktop application, so it does not have any built in authentication mechanism or RBAC.  You could solve it however with a reverse proxy and authentication, something like Nginx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. I recommend to you remove redisinsight as a docker service and use a local GUI for seeing the data. You can use DataGrip or the [redisinsight GUI](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/#insight-form) which looks pretty nice.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker already, why don't you take advantage of kubernetes as well? :D

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/
You can use k8s to deploy your image, wrap it with a secured ingress like so.